# Problema editar en un text_field Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select2

Tengo problema al querer editar un registro, no me lo carga en el text_field que tengo. El codigo de mi text_field es el siguiente: (todo esto se encuentra en mi archivo _form.html.erb)

```
<div class="form-group required">
 <%= form.label :speciality_id, class: 'control-label' %>
 <%= form.text_field :speciality_id, id: "speciality_admin", class: "form-control 
 required" %>
</div>
```

Y tengo un archivo js que me carga los posibles registros del select2

```
//specialities all
$("#speciality_admin").select2({
ajax: {
    url: "/specialities.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    cache: true,
    data: function (term, page) {
        return {
            q: term,
            page: page
        };
    },
    results: function (data) {
        var myResults;
        myResults = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, speciality) {
            myResults.push({
                'id': speciality.id,
                'text': speciality.name
            });
        });
        return {
            results: myResults
        };
    }
},
minimumInputLength: 3,
});
```

Hay alguna posibilidad de cuando edite me cargue el registro en ese select?

Comment: Algún error en la consola js? Carga al menos el componente de select2? Te logra hacer el request de Ajax? Te retorna datos? Has inspeccionado que efectivamente el input está almacenando el valor?

Comment: No, no me tira ningún error. la consola, ya que por ejemplo si yo presiono editar y luego presiono guardar, me guarda normalmente y no me lo guarda vacío sino que me guarda el valor que tiene sin ser modificado. Al select lo carga bien, solo que no visualizo el texto del select

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar tu input a un select de tal forma que tenga [al menos un option definido por defecto](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#default-pre-selected-values), algo como (no probado):

```
<%= form.select :speciality_id, 
                [form.object.speciality.try(:name), form.object.speciality_id], 
                id: "speciality_admin", class: "form-control required" %>
```